# Why doesn't this RewriteRule work for this URL?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I'm using this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^video/(.*)\.php$ /?video=$1 [L]
```

To rewrite this URL:

```
http://someSite.com/?video=bla-bla
```

As the following:

```
http://someSite.com/video/bla-bla.php
```

But nothing really happens. Anyone any idea why? I tested it with an online tool and on my own server.

**EDIT: the title string can contain everything. So it has to match everything.**
EDIT 2: it should be bla-bla.php and not bla-bla.

Comment: Where have you put this rule? Try `RewriteRule ^/?video/(.*)\.php$ /?video=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^video/(.*)$ /index.php?video=$1 [L]` should work

Comment: @DaveRandom In /etc/apache2 there is a file named "mydomain". That's where I put all the rules for this domain.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your situation, wouldn't <em>/video/bla-bla</em> point to a non-existent page? You sure you're not trying to rewrite <em>/video/bla-bla</em> to <em>?video=bla-bla</em>?

Comment: @Loolooii shouldn't it go in a .htaccess?

Comment: I suspect that's bad wording of the question rather than OP misunderstanding, but you are technically correct (the best kind of correct)

Comment: Ultimater, you're right. It should be bla-bla.php! I updated my question.

Comment: RewriteRule rewrites __incoming__ URLs, not outgoing. Your logic is backwards. Put the `http://someSite.com/video/bla-bla` in your HTML and use htaccess to rewrite that to `http://someSite.com/?video=bla-bla` for the server to process.

Comment: @KennethK.did you read the update to my question? See edit2 please. ?video=bla-bla should become /video/bla-bla.php.

Comment: @DaveRandom: `^/` - this is incorrect in 99% cases. The url passed to mod_rewrite doesn't start with `/`

Comment: @zerkms Depends where you put the rule, at the time I posted that comment he could have been putting it in httpd.conf. But I take your point.

Comment: @DaveRandom: oh, it really depends? Never knew that :-S And always amazed how people get `^/` worked

Comment: @zerkms Note also that the rule I suggested actually started with `^/?` so the leading slash is not mandatory but will be accepted. Still I suspect the problem here is that the file containing the rule is not being processed as a .htaccess, as the original expr looks good to me :-)

Comment: @DaveRandom: right. Double fault to me

Comment: @DaveRandom I just tried it in .htaccess file and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Loolooii Are you sure .htaccess files (or the original files you mentioned) are being processed by Apache? A quick and dirty way to test this is put something in there that's an obvious syntax error (e.g. put `This is a syntax error` on a line on its own) and it should cause the page to give you a 500 error. Come to that, are you certain the web server is Apache based?